# Parsing image with JSON from MySQL in android

Tags: android, mysql, json

I saw and read a lot of post here for this but I still can't get this images from mysql to my app. I also use one post code and tried to adopt for my app but still the app crashing. 
I've used this post [How to JSON parse images from mysql and populate listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205855/how-to-json-parse-images-from-mysql-and-populate-listview)

```
private ListView listView;
private StockAdaptor stockAdaptor;
String jsonResult = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.restaurants); //Just a listView, shown below
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurants);
    new JsonReadTask().execute("http://link"); //YOUR URL JSON SERVER, IF IT IS DIFFERENT FROM THAT SUPPLIED ABOVE
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true; //No options
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    stockAdaptor = new StockAdaptor(this); //Create a new StockAdaptor
}

public static String strFromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException { //Simple function, getting a String from an InputStream
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String cline;
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((cline = breader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(cline);
        out.append(newLine);
    }
    return out.toString();
}

private class StockAdaptor extends BaseAdapter { //The stocks list adaptor

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView menu;
        ImageView image; 
    }

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private RestaurantInformation[] stocks = null; //Array of stocks


    public StockAdaptor(Context context) {
        super();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setStockList(RestaurantInformation[] stocksinfo) {
        this.stocks = stocksinfo;// //////////////LITERALLY THIS

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return stocks.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return stocks[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder; //New holder
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_information, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // Creates the new viewholder define above, storing references to the children
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.menu = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);



            if (holder.image != null) {
                if (holder.image.getDrawable() == null) {
                    new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.image, null)                                 
                    .execute(stocks[position].image); //Download the image using the image

                }
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(stocks[position].name);
        holder.menu.setText(stocks[position].menu);

        return convertView;
    }
}

private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(params[0])) {
            final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                final HttpEntity httpentity = response.getEntity();
                if (httpentity != null){
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        inputStream = httpentity.getContent();
                        jsonResult = strFromStream(inputStream);
                        Log.i("", jsonResult);
                        return jsonResult;
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        //
                    } finally {
                        httpentity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ListDrwaer();

    }

}// end async task

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {

    try {
        if (jsonResult!=null) {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
            Vector<RestaurantInformation> restaurants = new Vector<RestaurantInformation>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                RestaurantInformation stock = new RestaurantInformation();
                stock.name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                stock.menu = jsonChildNode.optString("menu");
                stock.image = jsonChildNode.getString("image");
                Log.i("StockLog", stock.name + stock.menu + stock.image);
                restaurants.add(stock);
            }
            RestaurantInformation[] stocks = new RestaurantInformation[jsonMainNode.length()];

            int stockscount = jsonMainNode.length();
            for (int n = 0; n < stockscount; n++) 
            {               
                stocks[n] = restaurants.get(n);
            }
            stockAdaptor.setStockList(stocks);
            listView.setAdapter(stockAdaptor);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error; jsonResult null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView, View view) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    //
                }
            }

        }

    }

    Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)){

            final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                            + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                    return null;
                }

                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        inputStream = entity.getContent();
                        try {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                            int bytesRead;
                            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }   
                            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.toByteArray().length);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("IAE", "in stocks");
                            return null;
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        entity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            } finally {
                if (client != null) {
                    client.close();
                }
            }
            return null;

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And the `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error that I take in `LogCat` is this.

```
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Process: com.reserveme, PID: 831
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.reserveme.Restaurants.ListDrwaer(Restaurants.java:198)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.reserveme.Restaurants$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(Restaurants.java:184)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.reserveme.Restaurants$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(Restaurants.java:1)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Update:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                RestaurantInformation stock = new RestaurantInformation(); <--- THIS LINE
                stock.name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                stock.menu = jsonChildNode.optString("menu");
                stock.image = jsonChildNode.getString("image");
                Log.i("StockLog", stock.name + stock.menu + stock.image);
                restaurants.add(stock);
            }
```

UPDATE
This is server side `.php` file

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //replace with database hostname 
$username="user"; //replace with database username 
$password="pass"; //replace with database password 
$db_name="dbname"; //replace with database name

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from Restaurants"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json['Restaurants'][]=$row;
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Comment: Could you point out line number 198?

Comment: @Rohit5k2, sure, I've updated my question. `RestaurantInformation stock = new RestaurantInformation();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say but I don't think the line number you mentioned is line 198.

According to my calculation line nubmer 4 in following code snippet should be line nubmer 198 that is causing the NPE

```
1 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
2 JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
3 Vector<RestaurantInformation> restaurants = new Vector<RestaurantInformation>();
4 for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) 
5 {
6    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
7    RestaurantInformation stock = new RestaurantInformation();
     .........
```

Check if you are getting the value of `jsonMainNode` correctly. Base on analysis using your logcat and code, it seems that `jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");` is returning null and without checking for null you are using this in your for loop.

put a if condition for null to check the null value of `jsonMainNode` before the for loop.

Use if statement like this

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
Vector<RestaurantInformation> restaurants = new Vector<RestaurantInformation>();


if(jsonMainNode == null)
{
    Log.e("Inside if", "jsonMainNode is null here");
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) 
{
   JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
   RestaurantInformation stock = new RestaurantInformation();
```

Comment: When I double click on `LogCat` on this line `11-04 07:39:13.880: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.reserveme.Restaurants.ListDrwaer(Restaurants.java:198)
` it marks me this `RestaurantInformation stock = new RestaurantInformation();`

Comment: May be is important  or not but in MySQL I save only the path to image not the image. Can be this the problem?

Comment: Thats strange! But did you try putting a null check if statement?

Comment: Where to put this null statement? I mean isn't that this `try{}catch{}` block doing this?

Comment: I don't think try-catch block would check for null. It would check if it exists or not and also format (int, string, array etc). Just before the for loop use the if statement and see if it goes inside the if (Print a log or something)

Comment: What can I put in else statement so to log on `logcat` because the app just crashed. I've tried with Toast to see what happen but as you guess doesn't work

Comment: I've put  `if (jsonMainNode != null) { ... } else { //empty here }` and when crash gave me error in `logcat` on `11-04 08:45:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):  at com.reserveme.Restaurants.ListDrwaer(Restaurants.java:228)
`and `11-04 08:45:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):  at com.reserveme.Restaurants$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(Restaurants.java:201)
` line 201 is `ListDrwaer();` and line 228 is `RestaurantInformation[] stocks = new RestaurantInformation[jsonMainNode.length()];`

Comment: Ah, I see. Just a sec

Comment: Ok, `logcat` say `11-04 08:49:07.896: E/Inside if(1268): jsonMainNode is null here
`

Comment: See the value you are getting from json is null as I expected. Now keep this if in your code and if it is null handle it accordingly. And also If my answer helped you please accept it as your answer... :D

Comment: But why can be null i.e. empty? I'm sure that there is data in table?

Comment: That you need to check in your server code or may be json node name is different than you are using "metoxes"

Comment: You are right. In server side was another name. I've renamed it like in `.php` file and now I get this error `No value for image`.

Comment: In database I keep the path to image like `http://website/image.jpg` any idea why I get `no image`?

Comment: That means you don't have the image node in your json or may be name is different

Comment: Can you see my Update in question. I've posted server side `.php` file.

Comment: I don't know php much but I think I can help you. Do one thing for me. put this line `Log.d("data from server", "data: " + jsonResult.toString())` as the first line of method ListDrwaer() and give me the output?

Comment: I've put this `public void ListDrwaer() {
     Log.d("data from server", "data: " + jsonResult.toString());` but where to see the output? In the app I see again this `No value for image` and in logcat nothing but this `11-04 08:53:16.266: W/EGL_emulation(1319): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented`

Comment: Strange... Anyways the issue could be that node name in you json result is not "image" but something else or its not available in the object you are trying to fetch. You need to verify you json result.

Comment: What about my question how to store image and access it from DB? Is it problem how I trying now i.e. I store the path to image and the image in folder or I must save the actual image on DB as BLOB or LONGBLOB?

Comment: I am not sure about this. Let me go through some references before I can comment anything. But this is a totally different problem, why don't you post a new question for this.